# What is the logic behind the "using" keyword in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the logic behind the "using" keyword in C++?

It is used in different situations and I am trying to find
if all those have something in common and there is a reason
why the "using" keyword is used as such.

```
using namespace std; // to import namespace in the current namespace
using T = int; // type alias
using SuperClass::X; // using super class methods in derived class
```

Comment: Standard commitee hates introducing new keywords into C++ grammar.

Comment: I don't know if it is *the* logic, but I bet that's at least one of the reasons behind this choice. Oh and no need to harm yourself !

Comment: @user3111311: You do recognize the implications of introducing new reserved words, right?  It means that all existing code that used those as identifier names suddenly fails to compile.  That's a BAD THING.  For example, there's a lot of C code that can't compile as C++ because it contains things like `int class;`.  It would be even worse if C++ code suddenly stopped being valid C++.

Comment: @BenVoigt If that is the case then I see the logic.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The fact that C code using `int class;` won't compile as C++ isn't entirely a bad thing. It can be used to guarantee that C code will be compiled as C. It's too easy to forget that C and C++ are two different languages -- and, practically speaking, there is code that's valid C and valid C++ , but with different semantics.

Comment: In that respect, `using` is no worse (or better) than `static`. IMHO the point of not introducing new keywords is very important as explained by teh internets is made of catz and Ben Voigt.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

In C++11, the `using` keyword when used for `type alias` is identical to `typedef`.

7.1.3.2

> A typedef-name can also be introduced by an alias-declaration. The
> identifier following the using keyword becomes a typedef-name and the
> optional attribute-specifier-seq following the identifier appertains
> to that typedef-name. It has the same semantics as if it were
> introduced by the typedef specifier. In particular, it does not define
> a new type and it shall not appear in the type-id.

Bjarne Stroustrup provides a practical example:

```
typedef void (*PFD)(double);    // C style typedef to make `PFD` a pointer to a function returning void and accepting double
using PF = void (*)(double);    // `using`-based equivalent of the typedef above
using P = [](double)->void; // not valid in C++11
using P = auto(double)->void // Fixed thanks to DyP
```

Pre-C++11, the `using` keyword can bring member functions into scope. In C++11, you can now do this for constructors (another Bjarne Stroustrup example):

```
class Derived : public Base { 
public: 
    using Base::f;    // lift Base's f into Derived's scope -- works in C++98
    void f(char);     // provide a new f 
    void f(int);      // prefer this f to Base::f(int) 

    using Base::Base; // lift Base constructors Derived's scope -- C++11 only
    Derived(char);    // provide a new constructor 
    Derived(int);     // prefer this constructor to Base::Base(int) 
    // ...
};
```

---

Ben Voight provides a pretty good reason behind the rationale of not introducing a new keyword or new syntax. The standard wants to avoid breaking old code as much as possible. This is why in proposal documents you will see sections like `Impact on the Standard`, `Design decisions`, and how they might affect older code. There are situations when a proposal seems like a really good idea but might not have traction because it would be too difficult to implement, too confusing, or would contradict old code.

---

Here is an old paper from 2003 [n1449](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1449.pdf). The rationale seems to be related to templates. Warning: there may be typos due to copying over from PDF.

> First let’s consider a toy example:
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> class MyAlloc {/*...*/};
>
> template <typename T, class A>
> class MyVector {/*...*/};
>
> template <typename T>
>
> struct Vec {
> typedef MyVector<T, MyAlloc<T> > type;
> };
> Vec<int>::type p; // sample usage
> ```
>
> The fundamental problem with this idiom, and the main motivating fact
> for this proposal, is that the idiom causes the template parameters to
> appear in non-deducible context. That is, it will not be possible to
> call the function foo below without explicitly specifying template
> arguments.
>
> ```
> template <typename T> void foo (Vec<T>::type&);
> ```
>
> So, the syntax is somewhat ugly. We would rather avoid the nested `::type`
> We’d prefer something like the following:
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> using Vec = MyVector<T, MyAlloc<T> >; //defined in section 2 below
> Vec<int> p; // sample usage
> ```
>
> Note that we specifically avoid the term “typedef template” and
> introduce the new syntax involving the pair “using” and “=” to help avoid
> confusion: we are not defining any types here, we are introducing a
> synonym (i.e. alias) for an abstraction of a type-id (i.e. type
> expression) involving template parameters. If the template parameters
> are used in deducible contexts in the type expression then whenever
> the template alias is used to form a template-id, the values of the
> corresponding template parameters can be deduced – more on this will
> follow. In any case, it is now possible to write generic functions
> which operate on `Vec<T>` in deducible context, and the syntax is
> improved as well. For example we could rewrite foo as:
>
> ```
> template <typename T> void foo (Vec<T>&);
> ```
>
> We underscore here that one of the primary reasons for proposing
> template aliases was so that argument deduction and the call to `foo(p)`
> will succeed.

---

The follow-up paper [n1489](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1489.pdf) explains why `using` instead of using `typedef`:

> It has been suggested to (re)use the keyword typedef — as done in the
> paper [4] — to introduce template aliases:
>
> ```
> template<class T> 
>     typedef std::vector<T, MyAllocator<T> > Vec;
> ```
>
> That notation has the advantage of using a keyword already known to
> introduce a type alias. However, it also displays several
> disavantages among which the confusion of using a keyword known to
> introduce an alias for a type-name in a context where the alias does
> not designate a type, but a template; `Vec` is not an alias for a
> type, and should not be taken for a typedef-name. The name `Vec` is a
> name for the family `std::vector< [bullet] , MyAllocator< [bullet] > >`
> – where the bullet is a placeholder for a type-name. Consequently we
> do not propose the “typedef” syntax. On the other hand the sentence
>
> ```
> template<class T>
>     using Vec = std::vector<T, MyAllocator<T> >;
> ```
>
> can be read/interpreted as: from now on, I’ll be using `Vec<T>` as a
> synonym for `std::vector<T, MyAllocator<T> >`. With that reading, the
> new syntax for aliasing seems reasonably logical.

I think the important distinction is made here, *alias*es instead of *type*s. Another quote from the same document:

> An alias-declaration is a declaration, and not a definition. An alias-
> declaration introduces a name into a declarative region as an alias
> for the type designated by the right-hand-side of the declaration. The
> core of this proposal concerns itself with type name aliases, but the
> notation can obviously be generalized to provide alternate spellings
> of namespace-aliasing or naming set of overloaded functions (see ✁
> 2.3 for further discussion). [**My note: That section discusses what that syntax can look like and reasons why it isn't part of the proposal.**] It may be noted that the grammar production alias-declaration is acceptable anywhere a typedef
> declaration or a namespace-alias-definition is acceptable.

Summary, for the role of `using`:

- template aliases (or template typedefs, the former is preferred namewise)
- namespace aliases (i.e., `namespace PO = boost::program_options` and `using PO = ...` equivalent)
- the document says `A typedef declaration can be viewed as a special case of non-template alias-declaration`. It's an aesthetic change, and is considered identical in this case.
- bringing something into scope (for example, `namespace std` into the global scope), member functions, inheriting constructors

It **cannot** be used for:

```
int i;
using r = i; // compile-error
```

Instead do:

```
using r = decltype(i);
```

Naming a set of overloads.

```
// bring cos into scope
using std::cos;

// invalid syntax
using std::cos(double);

// not allowed, instead use Bjarne Stroustrup function pointer alias example
using test = std::cos(double);
```

Comment: It seems using is better to use than typedef, it allows separation of the type name on the left and the type definition on the right after =. But, I still see no reason why to call it "using". They could have picked a different keyword.

Comment: @user3111311 What other keyword did you have in mind? "auto"? "register"?

Comment: `using P = [](double)->void;` is, AFAIK, not valid C++11. This however is: `using P = auto(double)->void;` and produces a function type (such that `P*` is a function pointer).

Comment: His name is Bjarne Stroustrup ;) (note the second r in Stroustrup)

Comment: @RaymondChen: actually `register` wouldn't sound that bad, is in: `register X as Y`

Comment: Unfortunately `register` begins a variable declaration so this already has a meaning. Declare a register variable called Y of type X.

Comment: Can someone explain how adding a new keyword breaks old code? To my understanding, old code would not contain that keyword. So, I don't understand this argument. What am I missing here?

Comment: @EduardoReis: If we added a keyword "bang" suddenly all code like "int bang;" would become invalid.

Comment: @VexingParse, Thank you for pointing that out. It makes total sense.

Answer (score 3):

Another difference between **typedef** and **using**: you may do this:

```
    using vector3d_t = double[3];
    vector3d_t v = {1,2,3};
    v[1] = 4;
```

It is not possible with typedef:

```
    typedef double[3] vector3d_t; // Compilation error
```

Comment: It is possible, but the syntax needs to be fixed: `typedef double vector3d_t[3];`.  Look at the examples at [typedef](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef)

Comment: You simpy do not understand typedef syntax :)