# What is `using`, and what is the colon after the constructor in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop

Could you help me to understand the code below? I have an interface and need to write a code. But it first time when I work with OOP. I would be grateful if you answer some questions about this code.

```
template <class T, class Compare = std::less<T>>
class List_of_objects {
public:
  using IndexChange =
    std::function<void(const T& element, size_t new_element_index)>;

  explicit Heap(
    Compare compare = Compare(),
    IndexChange index_change = IndexChange());

// Other methods not important in my question

private:
IndexChange index_change_;
Compare compare_;

}

// Realization of methods
template<class T, class Compare>
List_of_objects<T, Compare>::List_of_objects(Compare compare, IndexChange index_change)
: compare_(compare), index_change_(index_change) {}
```

I have learned what `std::function<>` do from [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)  but I don't understand why we are writing `using` before 'IndexChange'

Also I have no idea what does `compare_(compare)` means, and what mean single colon in realization of `List_of_objects()`

I think that it is not difficult questions but I meet a deadline, I can't find answers in Stroustrup and in i-net:(

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions as one question. Ask a question for each question. And anyway, all those are in your book. You just didn't look hard enough.

Comment: Too broad? It's just two simple questions about the same piece of code.

Comment: @alain: Yes, but do you think a question about `using` *and* member initializer lists, posted under the title "several questions about classes and OOP in C++" (which the question is not about...) will help future visitors? Wouldn't a question "what is 'using'?" and one of "what is this colon?" be better? (Not only because we could have closed each of them satisfyingly with a single duplicate link each?)

Comment: @DevSolar Hmm, ok, fair points. I didn't think about closing as duplicates, that makes sense. Maybe the OP could edit the title, such that it is more specific. (Else I'll do it in a moment).

Answer (score 1):

```
using IndexChange = std::function<void(const T& element, size_t new_element_index)>;
```

permits you not to write the definition another time. This is a shortcut.

Then

```
IndexChange index_change_;
```

is the same as defining

```
std::function<void(const T& element, size_t new_element_index)> index_change_;
```

See : [What is the logic behind the "using" keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790932/what-is-the-logic-behind-the-using-keyword-in-c)

---

Concerning `compare_`, it is the attribute where its type is defined by the template argument `Compare` in your definition, and by default it is `std::less`.
So calling `compare_()` will call an instance of `std::less` or another class if you instantiate List_of_objects with another template argument. As for example : `List_of_objects<int, MyComparator>` then the class `MyComparator` will be used instead of `std::less`.

See : [Default template arguments for function templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447458/default-template-arguments-for-function-templates)

---

The part with the semicolons will initialize the members of your class.

See : [In this specific case, is there a difference between using a member initializer list and assigning values in a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/in-this-specific-case-is-there-a-difference-between-using-a-member-initializer)

Answer (score 0):

```
using IndexChange =
  std::function<void(const T& element, size_t new_element_index)>;
```

You can understand this as an abbreviation for a type. Instead of having to write `std::function<.....` you can simply use `IndexChange`, as it is done here:

```
  explicit Heap(
    Compare compare = Compare(),
    IndexChange index_change = IndexChange());
```

This is a constructor for `List_of_objects`:

```
List_of_objects<T, Compare>::List_of_objects(Compare compare, IndexChange index_change)
: compare_(compare), index_change_(index_change) {}
```

the part after the single colon initializes members with the parameters passed to the constructor.