# Use of "using" keyword as pseudo-preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, using

I've recently come across:

```
using vi = vector<int>;
using mvi = map<vi, int>;
```

Is it equivalent to #define? Is it correct to use this?

Comment: No, it is not "equivalent to #define". This is correct C++ syntax, so, in that sense, it is "correct" to use it.

Comment: It's actually an alternative to `typedef`, but more flexible.  Consider this more complex version: `template<typename T> using v = vector<T>;`

Answer (score 2):

This particular form has the same functionality as `typedef`. See this post for a good explanation of the `using` keyword: [What is the logic behind the "using" keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790932/what-is-the-logic-behind-the-using-keyword-in-c)

Also, it is not the same as `#define`. That is a pre-processor macro.