# Why do I get error "'cout' in namespace 'std' does not name a type" when I use "using cout = std::cout;"?

Tags: c++, c++11, using, type-alias

I'm trying to use shorter syntax and avoid using `std::` everywhere, so I started using new alias syntax. In some examples I saw people using it this way:

```
using json = nlohmann::json;
```

and tried this with `std::`, but with code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using cout = std::cout;

int main()
{
    cout << "Sometext";
    return 0;
}
```

but I get error `'cout' in namespace 'std' does not name a type`. I know I can use

```
using std::cout;
```

but why `using cout = std::cout;` doesn't work?

EDIT:

To all that votes to close this question: I posted it, because I wasn't able to find a solution, by writing by error message. Yes, question mentioned as one that has solution for my problem describes what happens, but when someone gets this sort of error, he will not find a solution easily. I just didn't realize, that `cout` is an object. I've read some questions like that, but still had no clue what happens.

Comment: Downvotes without comments are against new rules, that are described here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ so again, please comment on that. I would really like to make it better.

Comment: `using` declares types and type aliases.  `std::cout` is an object, not a type, so `using` can't create an alias for it.

Comment: @Staszek Also, no new *rules* were described in that blog post, people are still free to downvote as they wish

Comment: @Staszek that's a blog post, not new rules (and barely even qualifies as a new rule proposal)

Comment: Ok, it's not new rules. Still in this blog post author encourage people to be nicer. Isn't it against "be nice" policy to downvote question without stating reason, especially when it is not obvious?

Comment: @Staszek No, it's not, the be nice policy includes 1) Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.   2) Be welcoming, be patient, and assume good intentions.   3) Don't be a jerk. That blog post has also got a fairly bad [rep from a lot of people](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858/when-is-stack-overflow-going-to-stop-demonizing-the-quality-concerned-users-who), you won't necessarily get much support for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the logic behind the "using" keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790932/what-is-the-logic-behind-the-using-keyword-in-c)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`using cout = std::cout;` refers to [type alias declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) syntax. It's similar to `typedef`; so you're trying to declare a type named `cout` that refers to a previously defined type `std::cout`. But [`std::cout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) is not a type name, it's an object with type of [`std::ostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream).

As the error message said, it's just trying to tell you that `std::cout` doesn't refer to a type name.

Comment: The effect of `static auto& cout = std::cout;` is nearly indistinguishable from what OP tried, and would allow a different name.