# Implementing an iterator class for a my linked list. What is the using keyword?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I believe this is relatively new that an iterator class is required to have the following tags at the top of the class:

```
using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
using value_type = T;
using difference_type = int;
using pointer = T*;
using reference = T&;
```

Why are these necessary and what are they doing behind the scenes? (if anything)

Comment: No, it's nothing new...  They are aliases used to help make bug-free code.

Comment: This may already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790932/what-is-the-logic-behind-the-using-keyword-in-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `using` keyword is new in C++11.

In this instance, it's being used as a replacement for `typedef`.

Instead of writing:

```
typedef T value_type;
```

You can write this to get the same result:

```
using value_type = T;
```

See [What is the logic behind the "using" keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790932/) for more info.