# Is using std::time with std::srand valid code?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

It is legal in C++ to write:

```
std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
```

or does this yield undefined behaviour?

---

`std::time` returns a [`std::time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) which is an arithmetic type, but other than that unspecified. From my understanding, arithmetic type is any of the floating point, integer and character types.

`std::srand` takes an `unsigned int` as a seed value.

Therefore, I would think that you cannot strictly perform this conversion.
I read that on systems conforming to POSIX that `std::time_t` is integral and is the number of seconds since 00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC.
In this case, the conversion can entail converting from signed to unsigned, which is an implementation-defined conversion but should be OK, and from a larger integral to a smaller integral type which is fine too for the seed.

Comment: An arithmetic type can be converted to an `unsigned int` using one or more of the standard conversion rules.

Comment: Considering that `rand` is in the process of being deprecated in favor of the new `<random>` header, I wouldn't lose any sleep over this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, `time_t` may be a floating point type and if the result of truncating the value is not representable as `unsigned int`, then the behaviour is undefined ([conv.fpint]/1).

If you want to generate random numbers in a standard-conforming way, I suggest the C++11 `<random>` facilities. You can seed the RNGs from `std::random_device`. See, *e.g.,* https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666713/481267