# OpenGL C++ How do i get a random value?

Tags: c++

I want to create a forest like terrain using OpenGL and C++ in Visual Studio. Naturally, I want to place objects such as trees or bushes at random so it looks more natural. I wanted to do this by using the rand() function, but by using it, while the program is running, my objects are constantly changing location. I get that the program is in loop and because of that rand() is acting the way it is. I wanted to ask you guys if there is a good alternative to this. I just want to get a random location value for each object upon his creation and that that value stays constant. Here is a small part of the code which has this issue:

```
for (int i = -5.0; i < 5.0; i++){
    for (int j = -5.0; j < 5.0; j++){
        double k = i * 10.0 + ((rand() % 20 + 10) + ((rand() % 8 + 1) / 10.));
        double l = j * 10.0 + ((rand() % 20 + 10) + ((rand() % 8 + 1) / 10.));
        if (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0)
        {
            drvo(k, l);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help I get will be much appreciated!

Comment: Call rand() to get your random location, and then store that location value somewhere for future re-use (rather than calling rand() again for every object for every frame).  That way your objects will be randomly placed but stay in the same spot.

Comment: Try to use std::uniform_real_distribution<double> from C++11 <random> like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665818/generate-random-numbers-using-c11-random-library

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, i don't think i quite understood you. I added some lines outside the function which renders the scene:

`
int c = rand() % 20;
int a = c;
int d = rand() % 10;
int b = d;`

And changed the code a little bit:
`
for (int i = -5.0; i < 5.0; i++){
  for (int j = -5.0; j < 5.0; j++){
   double k = i * 10.0 + a + 10 + (b + 1) / 10.;
   double l = j * 10.0 + b + 10 + (a + 1) / 10.;
   if (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0)
   {
    drvo(k, l);
   }
  }
 }`

This method doesn't work since it always loads the same value. I am sure that i misunderstood you at some point.

Comment: You need to generate a separate set of random co-ordinates once for each object, and store that result with the object (or in an array, or something) so that you can reference the object's co-ordinates each time you redraw the object.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`rand` is not fully random, it's pseudorandom. Meaning that given the same seed, `rand` will produce the same values.

I suggest using `srand` to seed the PRNG with a seed that you save for later use.

When you want to render the scene again, call `srand` again with your saved seed and the sequence of `rand` calls should yield the same results.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But as I understand, every computer generated number is pseudo-random number. Because every random number generation algorithm are predefined and works on known inputs.

Comment: No computers can generate truly random numbers. Computers are deterministic and any algorithm for generating randoms really generate cyclic sequences of numbers (what differentiate good from bad generators is the length of those cycles).  Real sources of randomness are not that common or easy to use (a good one is given by radioactive material).

Comment: And my answer is not in contradiction with that. In a programming setting you need to pick your entropy source carefully if you rely on randomness (e.g: gambling, cryptography). There are commercially available devices that allow you to generate entropy as input for RNGs.

Comment: @Daelendil if this helped you please select it as answer

Comment: It didn't, for some reason, the srand function wouldn't work properly.