# Random numbers in C++11: is there a simple way to seed the generator in one place of the code, then use it in different functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Before C++11, I used `rand()` from `<cstdlib>` and it was very simple to choose to seed (or not) the generator in the `main()` function (for example), then use in libraryA random numbers generated by a function somewhere in libraryB. The code looked like this:

LibraryB (generates random numbers, old-fashioned way):

```
#include <cstdlib> // rand, RAND_MAX
double GetRandDoubleBetween0And1() {
   return ((double)rand()) / ((double)RAND_MAX);
}
```

Main program:

```
#include <cstdlib> // srand
#include <ctime> // time, clock
int main() {
   bool iWantToSeed = true; // or false,
                            // decide HERE, applies everywhere!
   if(iWantToSeed){
      srand((unsigned)time(0) + (unsigned int)clock());
   }
   // (...)
}
```

LibraryA (uses random numbers from LibraryB, generated according to the seed given in `main()`):

```
#include "../folderOfLibraryB/Utils_random.h" // GetRandDoubleBetween0And1
void UseSomeRandomness(){
   for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
      double nb = GetRandDoubleBetween0And1();
      // (...)
   }
}
```

Easy, right?

Now I would like to update `GetRandDoubleBetween0And1()` using the C++11 standards available via `#include <random>`. I have already read and seen the examples [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665818/generate-random-numbers-using-c11-random-library), but I don't see how to adapt it to my three modules. Surely, seeding the engine inside `GetRandDoubleBetween0And1()` is not the right thing to do...

Do you think I will have to pass the seeded engine from `main()` to `UseSomeRandomness()` in LibraryA, then from `UseSomeRandomness()` to `GetRandDoubleBetween0And1()` in LibraryB? Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do you think I will have to pass the seeded engine from main() to UseSomeRandomness() in LibraryA, then from UseSomeRandomness() to GetRandDoubleBetween0And1() in LibraryB?

Yes.

You instantiate the generator once, then pass a reference or pointer to it into whatever contexts want to use it.

This is just like dealing with any other resource.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <random>

inline double GetRandDoubleBetween0And1() {
    thread_local static std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};
    thread_local static std::uniform_real_distribution pick{0.0, 1.0};
    return pick(gen);
}
```

Being `inline` means you can put it in a header file and the compiler will create only one copy of the static objects which it will resolve at link time. However if you use it in a dynamic library you will get different copies. In that case you can put this function in its own library and link it to each program that uses the function.

The `thread_local` ensures thread safety (one random generator per thread) and being static they are only initialized once.

Answer (score 0):

My 'random' library provide a high convenient wrapper around C++11 random classes. You can do almost all things with a simple 'get' method.

For your use case you can use auto seeded random_static wrapper with static API.

Examples:

```
#include "effolkronium/random.hpp"

using Random = effolkronium::random_static;

auto Func( ) { 
   return Random::get(-10, 10 )
}

auto Func2( ) { 
   return Random::get(-10, 10 )
}

int main( ) {
    // Seed static internal engine
    Random::seed( MySuperSeed );

}
```

It is single header-only library.

Check out the github page:
https://github.com/effolkronium/random