# How can I random 3 different position in an 4x4 Array

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I have a task which is creating an Dungeon Escape game, based on a 4x4 array. I first have to create 3 different postion for E(Exit),K(Key) and P(Player). How can I random those 3 in 3 different position in an array ?
EDIT: I meant I need to find a way to random 3 DIFFERENT POSITION the neatest way. I already know about the rand() and srand thing.

Comment: Please do some research before asking questions here. You can simply google these kind of things and get your results.

Comment: you can read about rand function in c++ and as you working with array you know the range of index of array So simply generate random index of row and column for array values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `rand` function which is used to generate random number.

First of all you need to initialize random seed with `srand(time(NULL))`.

`myRandomNum = rand() % 4;` generate number between 0 and 3.

So, you can generate two number which would represent row index and column index and repeat that three times for: `E`(exit), `K`(key) and `P`(Player).

Comment: Initializing seed from current time is bad idea, because it's only updated once a second. Cleaner approach is to use [C++11 random](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666713/767632).

Comment: A) You probably want `rand() % 4;`, since OP has 4x4 array. B) You should say something about making sure the positions you get from `rand()` are *different*.

Comment: myRandomNum = rand() % 3; generate number between 0 and 3. Is it typo or wrong concept as this will only give number in range from 0 to 2

Comment: You should use the things provided in the C++ `<random>` header, instead of using outdated and bad C functions.

Comment: wait I meant I need to find a way to random 3 DIFFERENT POSITION the neatest way. I already know about the rand() and srand thing.