# How can I generate a random number in c++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the `rand()` which can generate a random number. However, I found that the code keep giving the same number when every time I compile it. 
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a = rand() % 11;
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random numbers using C++11 random library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665818/generate-random-numbers-using-c11-random-library)

Comment: You can use `srand(time(0))` function as a seed. If you don't use C++11 or after.

Comment: @ShadowMitia I tried this but it is not sui for my compiler. Thanks for helping!!

Comment: @SCMS You can try adding -std=c++11 to make it work, unless you can't use c++11 and beyond. But C++11 would make your life easier.

Comment: @SCMS what's your compiler. Most modern compilers already support C++11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to seed it at least 1 change to get random numbers every time you run the file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int random = rand();
    cout << "Seed = " << time(0) << endl;
    cout << "Random number = " << random << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is include the:`#include<time.h>` and use `srand` at the top of main. This will correct this issue because it will specify the seed for the generator.

```
// top of main
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
```

`time(0)` provides you with the seconds that have passed since Jan 1, 1970. This provides a good seed.

When you have time look into the `<random>` header [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/?kw=random)