# Reducing the number of times rand is called in shuffle algorithm

Tags: c++

I have implemented the Fisher-Yates algorithm to randomly shuffle my array.
Currently, I am calling the `rand()` function 8 times.  My question is: how could I only call the `rand()` function 6 times.
Here is my implementation:

```
class numbers{
private:
    static int indexCount;
    vector <vector <int> > list;
    vector<int> temp;

public:

    void swap (int *a, int *b)  
    {  
      int temp = *a;  
      *a = *b;  
      *b = temp;  
    }  

    int randomize (int arr[], int n)  
    {  
      RandomCount=0;

      for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)  
      {  
          int j = rand() % (i + 1);  
          RandomCount++;
          swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);  
      }
    }
```

I am trying to count how many times the `rand()` function is called, which is 8 because of the loop, but I am trying to get this number down to six while still randomising the array.

The array contains the values `{1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0}`.  I noticed because there are three 0's in my array, I may be able to swap them without using the `rand()` function. However, I am not sure what to do.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use the three zeros as a way to reduce the number of calls to `rand()` — you'd spend more time working out that there are three zeros.  In any case, you need to decide which random location to swap them to, so you have to call `rand()`.  Why do you think there's room for improvement?  (Your random number generation is slightly biassed because typically `RAND_MAX + 1` is not a multiple of `n`; that's easily fixed, though.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler my task description would only like the rand function to be called 6 times. but i am confused since there are 9 integers in the array so with only 6 rand calls i would not be shuffling the array

Comment: The way I read it, You are shuffling 9 numbers, therefore you need 8 random numbers. It does not matter that some of the numbers are the same or zero. I am not convinced that 6 will suffice -- even if some of them are the same, they still get different places in the final shuffle.

Comment: `rand()` can be thought of as returning at least 15 random bits (between 0 and at least 32767). Six calls to `rand()` can be thought of as returning at least 90 random bits. Is 90 bits of entropy enough to shuffle?

Comment: According to my math, 8 unique numbers can be shuffled into 8! permutations, or 40,320 permutations, which only needs 15.3 bits of entropy. If you have any given number duplicated twice, that's 6,720 permutations, which only needs 12.7 bits of entropy. This is THEORETICALLY possible. And I know it's been solved, about how to take these bits and get a uniform distribution. We have 90 bits of entropy, so this is extremely doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I will say that `rand()` is generally frowned upon as a random number generator – it's generally not a very good one, relies on hidden global state, and using `rand() % n` introduces bias. Since C++11 you're better off using the provided random number generators in `<random>`; [see this Q&A for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666713/6535915).

Sticking with your example, though, I'll assume your limit is six *calls* to `rand()`, and not necessarily six random *numbers*. As such, we can take advantage of the fact that the range of `rand()` (`RAND_MAX`, at least `32767`) is much larger than the size of the numbers you wish to generate (in this case, at most `9`). So, why don't we generate two numbers at once?

For example, if we need to get two random numbers in the range `A = [0,4)` and `B = [0,3)`, we can just make one random number in the range `X = [0, 4 * 3) = [0,12)`. Then, we can have `A = X % 4 = [0,4)` and `B = X / 4 = [0,3)` as uniformly-distributed random variables.

Doing this allows us to do two steps for each call to `rand()`. For an array of length 9, then, we have `9 = 4*2 + 1`, and so we can get away with only **5 calls to `rand()`**.

Translating your loop:

```cpp
RandomCount = 0;
int i = n - 1;

// first do the leftover element, if we have an odd array length
if (n % 2) {
  // (this is a terrible way to generate random numbers, but I'll stick with it)
  int j = rand() % (i + 1);
  RandomCount++;
  swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
  i--;
}

// now do the rest, two at a time
for (; i > 0; i -= 2)  
{  
  // get our two random numbers
  int r = rand() % ((i + 1) * i);
  RandomCount++;
  int a = r % (i + 1);  // number in [0, i+1)
  int b = r / (i + 1);  // number in [0, i)

  // do two swaps
  swap(&arr[i], &arr[a]);
  swap(&arr[i-1], &arr[b]);
}
```

You can probably do even better by using more of the random number. Note, however, that this will only work for sufficiently small sizes of `n`: if `n * (n-1) > RAND_MAX` then you'll run into problems, since you will not be able to generate sufficiently large random numbers.

---

To wrap your head around why the splitting works, let's consider the two values we get. Assume we want to get values in the range `A = [0,X)` and `B = [0,Y)`. We generate a number in the range `R = [0, X * Y)`.

- We can say that `A = R % Y = [0, Y)`. The `%` operator is the modulo, or remainder (for positive numbers), operator. That is, when dividing by `Y`, how much do we have left over? The possible values are all the numbers from 0 (`Y` divides evenly) through `Y-1`. Moreover, since the smallest number in `R` is 0, and the largest is one less than a multiple of `Y`, it is evenly distributed.
- We can say that `B = R / Y = [0, X)`. With integer floor division, any number in `R` from `0` to `Y-1` maps to `0` in `B`, any number from `Y` to `2Y-1` maps to `1` in `B`, and so forth. This goes up to our largest value, `XY-1`, which maps to `X-1` precisely.

You can think of this as a filled two-dimensional table of numbers, with `X` rows and `Y` columns. `R` chooses a random index into the table. When you take `R / Y` you get which row, and when you take `R % Y` you get which column.

Comment: thanks for this, does this produce the rand function 6 times?
i am currently getting a large number as my random count which can not be right

Comment: fixed the code and it calls the rand function 5 times instead of six, i am not sure why but it has to be six

Comment: If it has to be six, then call it one more time outside the loop without assigning it to anything. Boom - you've called it six times.

Comment: You're technically able to get away with generating random values for this problem using only 2 `rand()` calls, since you only need 4 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 21 bits total. But you'll have to deal with highly-biased results.

Comment: @John The "simple" way to only need 19 bits of entropy is to use a lookup table mapping each random number to a permutation, and if you mask the bits properly you can don't even get bias. (Well, assuming `rand()` isn't biased itself, which is unlikely.) That's more effort then I'm going to put into this, though ;)

Comment: @N.Shead apologies, I was talking to elie in regards to the ludicrous requirement that `rand()` must be called exactly six times. I think your implementation is about the appropriate level of effort required for this problem.

Comment: thankyou for this answer, with a few little tweaks i have made it work with your help. could you please explain a bit more how you are getting the two different random numbers. particularly the line
"int b = r / (i + 1); "
compared to
"int a = r % (i + 1); "

Comment: @elie1 I've updated my answer. I also had an off-by-one error (I knew I'd have one!) which I've fixed up. Hopefully it makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

### Introduction

I use the fact that uniform distributions of 2^N possible values only require N bits of entropy to be truly random. If we assume that our random process that produces these bits is random enough, then we can use less than half of a single call to `rand()` to generate the [0, 8), [0, 4), and [0, 2) distributions (3, 2, and 1 bits each).

### Problem Setup

[rand()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) produces a pseudo-random number between 0 and [RAND_MAX](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX), which is implementation defined, but guaranteed to be at least 32,767, or in hex, some number between [0x0000,0x7fff] inclusive. Therefore, `rand()` can be thought of as providing 15 random bits: 15 bits of entropy. I am not a randomness expert, and it is a known religious mantra that `rand()` is not sufficiently random, so a single call to `rand()` likely produces LESS THAN 15 bits of entropy. But I'm not a smart person, and I couldn't explain these limitations. So in grand academic tradition, I will assume them away. For purposes of this answer, `rand()` produces 15 truly unique bits of entropy.

Therefore, we assume that 6 calls of `rand()` produces 6 x 15 = 90 bits of entropy.

Shuffling a deck of 8 cards can generate `9!` (9 factorial) permutations: 362,880 possible unique permutations of cards. 362,880 permutations requires `log2(362,880) bits = ~18.5 bits` of entropy. This is *far* below our pool of 90 bits. However, we'll need these extra bits to reduce bias in some of our random picks, as we'll see, since `90 bits` is not cleanly divisible by `log2(362,880) bits`.

This is our pool of random bits:

```
[ r00 | r01 | ... | r13 | r14 ] <-- lower 15 bits from first call to rand()
[ r15 | r16 | ... | r28 | r29 ] <-- lower 15 bits from second call to rand()
 o
 o
 o
[ r75 | r76 | ... | r88 | r89 ] <-- lower 15 bits from sixth call to rand()
```

### How Many Bits Are Needed Per Iteration?

Let's see how many bits are theoretically needed per iteration of the shuffle algorithm.

For our 9 card deck, the first iteration picks one of the 9 cards, with equal probability, and places it at the end of the deck according to Fisher-Yates. To randomly select one of 9 options, we need `log2(9) = ~3.2 bits` of entropy.

The second iteration picks one of the remaining 8 cards, with equal probability, and places it at the new end of the deck. To randomly select one of 8 options, we need `log2(8) = 3 bits` of entropy.

We go through all picks to see how many bits each step needs:

```
Iteration | Choices | Bits Required
----------+---------+--------------
        0 |       9 | about   3.17
----------+---------+--------------
        1 |       8 | exactly 3
----------+---------+--------------
        2 |       7 | about   2.81
----------+---------+--------------
        3 |       6 | about   2.58
----------+---------+--------------
        4 |       5 | about   2.32
----------+---------+--------------
        5 |       4 | exactly 2
----------+---------+--------------
        6 |       3 | about   1.58
----------+---------+--------------
        7 |       2 | exactly 1
----------+---------+--------------
        8 |       1 | exactly 0
```

For iterations that require an integral number of bits (i.e., steps 1, 5, and 7, which each have 2^3, 2^2, and 2^1 possible values) we only need that exact number of bits in order to select these values. Our first `rand()` call has 15 bits of entropy we can use! Just take 6 of those. We have 84 bits left to distribute to the other iterations as needed. We can just call `rand()` once for all of these three special cases and take the bits we need.

How many bits should we assign to the other 5 iterations (i.e., step 0, 2, 3, 4, and 6)? Well, the naive implementation of your code would have just used 15 bits for each iteration (since each call to `rand()` produces 15 bits of entropy). If that was "random enough" for what you wanted in the first place, we can just do that for each of these 5 iterations. That code would look like this:

### An Implementation

```
// changed return type to void since this doesn't return anything
void randomize (int arr[], int n)
{
  // generate our bit pool for uniform distributions of size 2^n
  int integral_rand_pool = rand();

  for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)  
  {
      int j;
      if (i == 7)
      {
        // need 3 bits of entropy
        j = integral_rand_pool & 0x07;
        integral_rand_pool = integral_rand_pool >> 3;
      }
      else if (i == 3)
      {
        // need 2 bits of entropy
        j = integral_rand_pool & 0x03;
        integral_rand_pool = integral_rand_pool >> 2;
      }
      else if (i == 1)
      {
        // only need 1 bit of entropy
        j = integral_rand_pool & 0x01;
        integral_rand_pool = integral_rand_pool >> 1;
      }
      else
      {
        // need a non-integral number of bits. Just grab 15 from rand()
        j = rand() % (i + 1);
      }  
      swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);  
  }
}
```

This completes the problem with the same amount of bias as calling `rand()` 8 times, by only calling `rand()` 6 times.

---

### Can We Reduce Our Bias?

If we have N random bits, and we want to produce a number between [0, M), and we produce our random numbers by generating a random number between [0, (2^N) - 1] and taking the modulo M, we will always have some bias towards selecting numbers in the lower end of our range if (2^N) is not a multiple of M. We can reduce this bias simply by increasing N.

If we want to reduce our bias, then, the naive way to do is is just increase the number of bits we use in each of the non-integral-entropy steps. How many do we increase it by? Well we know from above that we have 90 total bits of entropy. Three of our iterations take 6 of those bits and produce no bias, respectively. That leaves 84 bits for our remaining 5 iterations, or just over 16 bits per iteration. Our first `rand()` pool has 9 bits sitting in it that we don't use.

If we take just one of these bits and append it to the result of `rand()` for each of the non-integral-bit values, we can slightly reduce our bias per number. We have four bits left over after this, and a deeper study of how to measure bias in random numbers could be used to determine which iteration is more worthy of the extra bit. But at this point, it's becoming very complicated looking code, and you're better off using the standard `<random>` library.

See [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171012154111/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65653.html) for additional reading.

Comment: thankyou for the code, this calls the rand function 7 times

Comment: What is the initial value of n? I thought it was 9. Because I only see this calling `rand()` 6 times. Unless you're calling `rand()` an additional time in your code that you're not showing us.

Comment: n is 9, which is the size of the array. i checked my code and i only increment my random count after you change the value of j
eg.
 if (i == 7)
      {
        // need 3 bits of entropy
        j = integral_rand_pool & 0x07;
        indexCount=indexCount+1;
        integral_rand_pool = integral_rand_pool >> 3;
      }
and then did that for each if statement

Comment: You should only increment your random count when `rand()` is called. That should be 6 calls total.

Comment: i appreciate the answer john, however i have chosen to go with the other answer as i believe i am able to understand the code more without confusing myself

Comment: That's fine, my feelings aren't hurt. I think the other answer is just fine as well.