# What does this `randfloat()` do?

Tags: c++

I saw some C++ code:

```
  float randfloat(float a, float b)
  {
    uint32_t val = 0x3F800000 | (rng.getU32() >> 9);
    float fval = *(float *)(&val);
    return a + ((fval - 1.0f) * (b - a));
  }
```

The complete code is on a [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/Treeki/85be14d297c80c8b3c0a76375743325b). It seems to first bitwise OR the binary number `111111100000000000000000000000` with an unsigned random integer that is shifted right by 9 positions.

And then the bits are treated as a float, and made into a float?  I would have guessed that it returns a float that is a random number between `a` and `b`, with `a` *inclusive* and `b` *exclusive*.  So some other parts of the code uses `randfloat(0.9, 0.85)` and I think it is "almost" the same as `randfloat(0.85, 0.9)`, except the first case is exclusive of `0.85`, while the second case is exclusive of `0.9`.

Does somebody know what is going on with the part `0x3F800000 | (rng.getU32() >> 9)` and making it a float -- is it IEEE 754?

Comment: Not completely related, but `*(float *)(&val);` invokes *undefined behavior*. So strictly speaking this entire function invokes UB

Comment: Strictly speaking `float fval = *(float *)(&val)` is undefined behavior. The portable alternative would be to `memcpy` from `val` to `fval`. You should check that they are the same size with something like `static_assert(sizeof(val) == sizeof(fval));`.

Comment: is this common used in certain platforms... this actually might be the code that runs on a Nintendo Switch... but the person who extracted the code might have ported it to the Intel processor and C++ that commonly can be compiled and run on a Mac or PC...

Comment: Btw. have fun with [h-schmit](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) and you can most probably figure this out.

Comment: This type of pointer casting to set arbitrary memory representation for floats is an old trick that is probably best known for the [Quake Fast Inverse Square Root](https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-quakes-fast-inverse-square-root/). It looks like the intention is to set the first 9 bits to 1 and randomize the rest of the bits. I believe in IEEE 754 the first bit is the sign, and the next 8 are the exponent. Assuming that is the target representation, it looks like it wants `fval` to be a random `float` but with all exponent and sign bits set. It is not a portable approach.

Comment: Looks like someone was upset at the performance of the floating point random number generator and came up with this *concoction*.

Comment: That's why I like the caliber of C++ programmers... so using https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html, it seems it is to skip the left most 2 bits (have them as `0`), and then get a number from `1.0` to `1.9999999...`, and so `fval - 1.0f` is just to get a number from `0.0` to `0.9999....`

Comment: But when Francois said "set the first 9 bits to 1" that was wrong, the two highest bits are zero.

Comment: @tadman true... couldn't the code just use `rand()` to get a number from `0.0` to `0.99999....` with `0` inclusive and `1` exclusive?

Comment: It probably could, but I have a feeling that may have under-performed compared to this code. I'm not saying this code is great or even trustworthy, but I bet it's pretty fast. In C++ you'd tend to steer towards using the [random number generation facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and stay far, far away from `rand()` which is not really random, not performant.

Comment: I see... so you are saying in general, always use the functions provided using `#include <random>` and some sample is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665818/generate-random-numbers-using-c11-random-library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x3f800000` is the binary representation of `1.0f` when stored in the IEEE-754 `binary32` single-precision format. This format has 23 stored significand (mantissa) bits. These bits are filled with the 23 high order bits returned by a 32-bit PRNG, resulting in a pseudo random number in [1, 2). Subtracting `1.0f` from the result gives a random number in [0, 1), which is then scaled to the interval [a, b] or [a, b), depending on how rounding works out for a specific pair `a`, `b`.

As others have already pointed out in comments, the type-punning idiom used in this code to reiterpret a `float` as a `uint32_t` is unsafe, as it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: "0x3f800000 is the binary representation of 1.0f" - you're in my pub quiz team. +1.

Comment: pub quiz team... like they play games in a bar drinking beer and ask quiz questions such as what is the capacity of a floppy disk used for Apple II?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a rather pathetic attempt to retrieve a random number in the interval `[a, b)` which is perhaps unwittingly exponentially distributed depending on how the mantissa and exponent are arranged, and the endianness of `uint32_t` on your platform. The behaviour of the code is undefined due to the cast violating *strict aliasing*.

Bin it and replace with

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 e(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(a, b);   
dist(e); // a drawing
```

This is portable and passes very many statistical tests of randomness. Of course, the first three statements are all to do with setting up the generator - don't call that repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

The below attempts to form a random number in the range [1.0f...2.0f) by fixing the exponent and filling with a random significant.

```
uint32_t val = 0x3F800000 | (rng.getU32() >> 9);
float fval = *(float *)(&val);
```

Lots of UB.

A simple alternative is

```
float fval = (rng.getU32() >> 9)/8388608.0f;  // divide by 2^23
```

or

```
float fval = ldexpf(rng.getU32() >> (32-23), -23);  // divide by 2^23
```

Comment: I wonder if the OP appreciates that this does not generate uniformly distributed numbers? Nice analysis though, +1.

Comment: @Bathsheba Given a fair `rng()`, I see this as a fair [0....1.0f) distribution. Once `* (b - a)` occurs, I agree with you: uniformity is reduced/lost.