# random() and randomize() not working in vs code(cstdlib & ctime is included)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    system("cls");
    cout<<randomize();
    cout<<random();
    return 0;
}
```

It is giving an error:
identifier "random() is undefined","randomize() is undefined".
I have just installed VS code and mingw and have set the path of mingw also i have installed the extensions C/C++ by Microsoft and Code runner in VS code.

Comment: Where did you get those function names from? Standard C++ doesn't have such functions. [`random()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/random) seems to be a POSIX function (i.e. it'd work if you were on Linux, not sure if there's a way to get it work on MinGW), and I can't find any information on `randomize()`.

Comment: That you're not using [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)  and all its glory in a modern C++ program is itself a proper question to consider. Just saying.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat this code is working in turbo c++ ;(

Comment: @RishabhSingh I can believe in those two functions working in Turbo C++, but the whole code couldn't have worked, because Turbo C++ doesn't have namespaces. Turbo C++ is an ancient compiler from the previous millenium. It predates the earliest C++ standard, so it's noticeably different compared to modern compilers, which all try to adhere to the same standard.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yup you are right, thanx though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for:

- [`std::srand()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) to set the seed (randomize)- but you'll have to provide an argument to make it more random
- [`std::rand()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) to get a random number (random)

But if you want to do more elaborate work with random numbers in C++, it'll be worth to have a look at the real C++ [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library and at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19665818/3723423)