# Why is my C++ code adding nonsense to the end of my ASCII string?

Tags: c++, ascii

I'm quite new to C/C++, and I'm putting together a bad knuckle tattoo generator to get used to using strings and seeded random values.
The programme should initialise a 9-character string to hold the final knuckle tattoo, generate 2 random sequences of 4 letters using their ASCII values, and then output this to the console.
This isn't meant to be particularly good or sexy, I'm just using it to get used to working with arrays and generating random values.
This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void randomKnuckleTatt(char inputString[]);

void main()
{
    char knuckleTatt[9]; //Will hold final tattoo output

    srand((unsigned int)time(nullptr)); //Seeding rand(void)

    randomKnuckleTatt(knuckleTatt); //Generate a random knuckle tattoo and add to knuckleTatt
    cout << "Your bad knuckle tatt is:\n"
      << knuckleTatt << endl;
}

void randomKnuckleTatt(char inputString[])
{
    int i;
    int randomValue;

    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        randomValue = int(double(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 25 + 65); //Generate random integer and fit to range
        randomValue = char(randomValue); //Cast as char
        inputString[i] = randomValue; //Assign random ASCII letter to array element
    }

    inputString[4] = char(32);

    for (i = 5; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        randomValue = int(double(rand()) / RAND_MAX * 25 + 65);
        randomValue = char(randomValue);
        inputString[i] = randomValue;
    }
}
```

So far, `randomKnuckleTatt` successfully generates a valid knuckle tattoo (ie. two four-letter words separate by a space) from random ASCII values and modifies the `knuckleTatt` array with these values.
However, when `knuckleTatt` is printed to the console with `cout`, loads of nonsense ASCII characters are also printed. It always prints the characters contained in `knuckleTatt`, along with seven of "╠" (ASCII 204 in decimal, if that's not displaying properly for anyone), and then some more junk characters - for example, the most recent output was "UXDP TTKJ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠²┘▬*­¸╗".

I've added a break point in debug on `cout << "Your bad knuckle tatt is:\n"`, and `knuckleTatt` only contains the 9 ASCII characters generated in `randomKnuckleTatt`.

Why is this happening, and how do I stop it?

Comment: "_Why is this happening_" You didn't null-terminate your string.

Comment: Two four letter words = 8 characters; the space in between makes 9 characters. Then, the **required NULL terminator** makes 10 characters. So, your `knuckleTatt` array isn't large enough.

Comment: Nonsense on the end of strings is universally because of a failure to terminate them. Remember that.

Comment: Note that your `randomKnuckleTat()` function has no way of knowing that the provided pointer allocates enough storage for 10 characters. You'd be better of using e.g. `std::array<char, 10>` or an `std::string`. Some other remarks: you should be using [random number generators provided in `<random>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665818). [Don't use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721).

Comment: Also, look at e.g. [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n). Using it would make your code more expressive, i.e. it will be easier to see at a glance what it's doing, instead of having to read all the code.

Comment: Thanks guys. For now, I've just extended my array to 10 characters and null-terminated it manually, which has fixed the issue, but I'll definitely look into all those suggestions (eg. using ```namespace std;``` and random number generators in a more refined way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the room of the null terminator/character (`\0`) to terminate the character string. So make your array bigger and set the last value to `\0`.

Use `std::string` next time.

Comment: Note that it is misleading to call the null terminator character "NULL" as that may lead someone to think that the NULL macro has something to do with the terminator character.

Comment: Thanks - as mentioned above, I get that I'm not doing this in the most efficient way, so I appreciate any suggestions as to how I can move more towards "good practice" :)