# Can we define an enum variable like an array?

Tags: c++, enums

i have below enum :

```
enum words= {dog, cat, horse, hen, goat, pig, sheep};
```

can i assign a new enum constant as below :

```
words word = words[4];
```

What i want to do is get a random number between 0 and words.size() .and i want to pick that word from the enum . is it possible?

```
int wordno = (rand()%8);

words word = (words)wordno;
```

Comment: `words word = (words)wordno;` would work. Why do you need operator `[]` while cast could achieve it?

Comment: Shivani Garg, With 7 in `{dog, cat, horse, hen, goat, pig, sheep};`, `int wordno = rand()%7;` makes more sense.

Comment: If you add an additional element `num_words` to the `enum`, then this element will have the value of the number of elements in the array. You can then use `num_words` instead of hard-coding the value `7` or `8`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `enum` declaration is a bit wrong. It should be

```
enum words {dog, cat, horse, hen, goat, pig, sheep};
```

Since C++11 it is usually also better to use an `enum class` instead, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum) for details:

```
enum class words {dog, cat, horse, hen, goat, pig, sheep};
```

---

Note that `enum` enumerators already have a numeric value. If you don't specify these numeric values manually, they are from left-to-right starting from zero increasing by one. So e.g. `horse` has the numeric value `2` in your enumeration.

However, it is not directly allowed to convert between the numeric value and the enumeration implicitly. If you need to do that, you must use `static_cast`:

```
auto word = static_cast<words>(wordno);
```

When doing this, you need to be careful however (which is also why the explicit cast is required), because you are not allowed to cast an integer value that is outside the range of numeric values of the enumeration in this way. In your code you do `rand()%8` which can return values up to `7`, but the largest numeric value in your enumeration is `6` for `sheep`. You would have undefined behavior with that.

`auto` can be replaced by `words`. It just lets the compiler figure out the correct type, so I don't have to write it twice. (It is already in the `static_cast`.)

As a sidenote, `rand` is not a good random number generator for many reasons (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869166/why-is-the-use-of-rand-considered-bad)). Since C++11 you can use the more modern [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665818/generate-random-numbers-using-c11-random-library).

Also as a sidenote I suggest avoiding C-style casts such as `(words)wordno`. Instead use `static_cast` as I showed above. You are much less likely to make serious mistakes this way, since the C-style casts are usually too permissive in what casts they allow.

---

For `words word = words[4];`, this syntax does not work. But it is not really necessary, since as above, you can initialize `word` directly with the value `4` with an explicit cast.

```
auto word = static_cast<words>(4);
```

But if you are intending to assign a constant value, you should just use the enumerator directly. That is what they are for:

```
auto word = words::goat;
```

Comment: i want the enum to take a different constant value (from the given values in {}) in every run. but in this case it just takes the value to be the random number that is generated. Instead i want it to hold the values as 'dog' or'cat'

Comment: @ShivaniGarg It is not clear to me what you mean. After the assignment, `word` will be of type `words` and hold one of `words::dog`, `words::cat`, etc. randomly.

Comment: int main(){
 
 enum words { dog, cat, horse, hen, goat, pig, sheep}
  srand(time(0));
int wordno = (rand()%7);
//words word = (words)wordno;

words word = static_cast<words>(wordno);

std::cout<<word<<std::endl;
}

now the output is a integer whereas i want the output to be the string ,e.g. dog

Comment: @ShivaniGarg The name of an enumerator is a purely compile-time concept. You cannot get a string to print from an enumerator's name, the same as you can't get a string to print from a variable's name. If you want to assign strings to the enumerators, write a function that uses `switch` on `words` and returns the corresponding string to each enumerator.