# Generate random graph with probability p

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, probability

> Write a function in main.cpp, which creates a random graph of a certain size as follows. The function takes two parameters. The first parameter is the number of vertices n. The second parameter p (1 >= p >= 0) is the probability that an edge exists between a pair of nodes. In particular, after instantiating a graph with n vertices and 0 edges, go over all possible vertex pairs one by one, and for each such pair, put an edge between the vertices with probability p.

How to know if an edge exists between two vertices .

Here is the full question
[image]

PS: I don't need the code implementation

Comment: You are supposed to randomly decide whether there is an edge between any two vertices (with probability `p`, independently presumably)

Comment: Are you looking for an adjacency list or matrix?

Comment: How to determine if an edge exists ? Can you give me a function which takes two vertex and probability p and returns true if there should be an edge else false.

Comment: @infinitezero matrix

Comment: See [Generate random numbers using C++11 random library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665818/generate-random-numbers-using-c11-random-library)

Comment: @user17732522 but what about the probability p ?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am not sure why you removed the c++ tag. It seems OP just wants to know how to get random numbers in C++.

Comment: @ChandrapalSingh What about it?

Comment: @user17732522 the question isn't entirely clear but contains no code and they're explicitly not asking for code so i can't see how it's c++ related?

Comment: @AlanBirtles OK, true. The comments say otherwise though. In any case, I voted to close for lack of clarity.

Comment: hey @ChandrapalSingh my previous algorithm was biased. @user17732522 pointed that out and I amended it. Please look at the `else` clause that I added to the algorithm section. Please read the comments under the answer which explain what the problem was. If you need further explanation, please ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem statement clearly says that the first input parameter is the number of nodes and the second parameter is the probability `p` that an edge exists between any 2 nodes.

What you need to do is as follows (Updated to amend a mistake that was pointed out by @user17732522):

```
1- Create a bool matrix (2d nested array) of size n*n initialized with false.
2- Run a loop over the rows:
  - Run an inner loop over the columns:
    - if row_index != col_index do:
        - curr_p = random() // random() returns a number between 0 and 1 inclusive
        - if curr_p <= p: set matrix[row_index][col_index] = true
          else: set matrix[row_index][col_index] = false
          - For an undirected graph, also set matrix[col_index][row_index] = true/false based on curr_p
```

**Note:** Since we are setting both cells (both directions) in the matrix in case of a probability hit, we could potentially set an edge 2 times. This doesn't corrupt the correctnes of the probability and isn't much additional work. It helps to keep the code clean.

If you want to optimize this solution, you could run the loop such that you only visit the lower-left triangle (excluding the diagonal) and just mirror the results you get for those cells to the upper-right triangle.
That's it.

Comment: Thanks  . @user17732522 tried to explain me but you made it clear .

Comment: you're welcome, happy to help :D

Comment: That's a bit unclear. If you set `matrix[x][y]` to `true`, but do not set `matrix[y][x]` at the same time, it means the node `x` is connected to the node `y` whilst node `y` remains _not_ connected to `x`. This implies you're building a _directed_ graph. That, however, has not been defined in the problem statement, so I would rather assume the graph should be undirected.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that you, @CiaPan I'll amend my answer accordingly

Comment: It now sets edges with wrong probability. You should not have two chances of putting an any specific edge.

Comment: I was thinking since we do this for every node equally, the probability stays correct. @user17732522

Comment: For optimization, we can run the loop only on the lower left triangle mirror it on the upper right.

Comment: With the current code in the undirected case, the probability that `matrix[0][1]` will be set is the probability that the random number in the iteration with col=0/row=1 _or_ in the iteration with col=1/row=0 is smaller than `p`. That probability is `1-(1-p)^2`.

Comment: You are right, @user17732522 the probability of all the nodes is biased towards not being connected compared to the given probability. Thank you for pointing that out. I learned a good lesson :D. I have to run. Will come back later and ammend that. Thanks again.