# how to get a variable from a string function to main

Tags: c++, string, function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void welcome();
void goodbye();
void CheckLadders();
void CheckChutes();
int spin();
string orderPlay();


const char YES = 'Y';
const int MAX = 6;
const int MIN = 1;
int currPos1, currPos2, dice, newPos1, newPos2;
const int END = 100;
string playerName1, playerName2;


int main()
{
    srand(time(0)); // srand(time(NULL));
    newPos1 = 0;
    newPos2 = 0;
    currPos2 = 0;
    currPos1 = 0;
    char choice;
    //dice = 0;
    //initialize all the variables as zero (reset)
    do{
        //while (newLocation < 100 && currentLocation >= 99)
        orderPlay();
        cout << "Press enter to spin...";
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "You threw " << dice << ".";
        spin();

        cout << playerName1 << "Your current location is: " << currPos1 << endl;
        cout << playerName2 << "Your current location is: " << currPos2 << endl;

        if (playerTurn == "p1" || playerTurn == "P2"){ //call plyerTurn from orderPlay...dont knw if its correct
            newPos1 = currPos1 + dice;
            cout << playerName1 << "Your new location is: " << newPos1 << endl; 
        }else{
            newPos2 = currPos2 + dice;    
            cout << playerName2 << "Your new location is: " << newPos2 << endl;
        }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        cout << "Do you want to play again? (y/n) ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;
    } while (choice == YES);

    if(choice != YES)
        goodbye();

    return 0;
}

void welcome(){

    cout << "Welcome to the chutes and ladders game. Both " << endl;
    cout << "players start at 0, and the first one to 100 " << endl;
    cout << "wins the game. However, if you land on a chute," << endl;
    cout << "your player will move down, but a ladder " << endl;
    cout << "will move you up." << endl;
}
void goodbye(){

    cout << endl
         << endl;
    cout << "Thank you for playing the game, I hope you enjoyed it!";
    cout << endl
         << endl;
}
int spin(){

    dice = rand() % ((MAX - MIN) + 1) + MIN;

return dice;
}
string orderPlay(){ // should only be for player turn without names i think
  string playerTurn;
  cout << "Please initiate which player is going first (P1/P2): ";
  cin >> playerTurn;

  if (playerTurn == "P1" || playerTurn == "p1"){
    cout << "Player 1 enter your name: ";
    getline(cin, playerName1);
    cout << endl;
    cout << playerName1 << "'s turn" << endl;
    cout << endl;
  }else{
    cout << "Player 2 enter your name: ";
    getline(cin, playerName2);
    cout << endl;
    cout << playerName2 << "'s turn" << endl;
    cout << endl;
  }

return playerTurn;
}

void CheckChutes (int NewPos)
{
    //checks for chutes

    if (NewPos == 98)
        NewPos = 78;
    else if (NewPos == 95)
        NewPos = 75;
    else if (NewPos == 93)
        NewPos = 70;
    else if (NewPos == 87)
        NewPos = 24;
    else if (NewPos == 64)
        NewPos = 60;
    else if (NewPos == 62)
        NewPos = 19;
    else if (NewPos == 56)
        NewPos = 53;
    else if (NewPos == 49)
        NewPos = 11;
    else if (NewPos == 48)
        NewPos = 26;
    else if (NewPos == 16)
        NewPos = 6;
    else
        NewPos = NewPos;
    cout << "You landed on a chute, and have to move down" << endl;
}

void CheckLadders (int NewPos)
{
    //checks for ladders

    if (NewPos == 1)
        NewPos = 38;
    else if (NewPos == 4)
        NewPos = 14;
    else if (NewPos == 9)
        NewPos = 21;
    else if (NewPos == 23)
        NewPos = 44;
    else if (NewPos == 28)
        NewPos = 84;
    else if (NewPos == 36)
        NewPos = 44;
    else if (NewPos == 51)
        NewPos = 66;
    else if (NewPos == 71)
        NewPos = 90;
    else if (NewPos == 80)
        NewPos = 100;
    else
        NewPos = NewPos;
    cout << "You landed on a ladder, and get to move up the board!" << endl;
}
```

I am fairly new to C++ and programming overall, I am in the middle of doing my assignment chutes and ladders, and I have encountered a problem.

I don't know how to use the playerTurn variable from orderPlay function in the main function, please be nice I know this might sound stupid, all help is greatly appreciated.

please disregard the comments some of them are stupid.

Comment: The `orderPlay` function returns the string `playerTurn`, so to use it in the main function, store it into a variable like `const string playerTurn = orderPlay();`.

Comment: While not strictly related to your main question, there are several other problems in your code. **1)** [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/12122460) **2)** `unistd.h` is not part of the C++ standard library, and since it's not used anywhere in your code, remove it. **3)** With C++11 or newer, there's a more modern way to generate random numbers. See [Generate random numbers using C++11 random library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19665818/12122460).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `orderPlay` function returns the string `playerTurn`, so to use it in the main function, store it into a variable like this:

`const string playerTurn = orderPlay();`

*credit to [kotatsuyaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12122460/kotatsuyaki) who posted the answer in the comments*